# EF core DbContext in a multithreaded API application

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

> **tl;dr** How can I use Entity Framework in a multithreaded .NET Core API application even though DbContext is not threadsafe?

#### Context

I am working on a .NET Core API app exposing several RESTful interfaces that access the database and read data from it, while at the same time running several TimedHostedServices as background working threads that poll data regularly from other webservices and store them into the database.

I am aware of the fact that DbContext is not threadsafe. I read a lot of docs, blog Posts and answers here on Stackoverflow, and I could find a lot of (partly contradictory) answers for this but no real "best practice" when also working with DI.

#### Things I tried

Using the default `ServiceLifetime.Scoped` via the `AddDbContext` extension method results in exceptions due to race conditions.

I don't want to work with locks (e.g. Semaphore), as the obvious downsides are:

- the code is polluted with locks and try/catch/finally for safely releasing the locks
- it doesn't really seem 'robust', i.e. when I forget to lock a region that accesses the DbContext.
- it seems redundant and 'unnatural' to artificially syncronize db access in the app when working with a database that also handles concurrent connections and access

Not injecting `MyDbContext` but `DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>` instead, building the context only when I need to access the db, using a `using` statement to immediatelly dispose it after the read/write seems like a lot of resource usage overhead and unnecessarily many connection opening/closings.

#### Question

I am really puzzled: how can this be achived?

I don't think my usecase is super special - populating the db from a Background worker and querying it from the web API layer - so there should be a meaningful way of doing this with ef core.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *seems like a lot of resource usage overhead and unnecessarily many connection opening/closings* - no it is not because of connection pooling

Comment: The scoped lifetime should be the right one, as every request happens in its own thread and also starts a new scope. I never had such issues so please show some code where you had such an issue

Comment: @Sir Rufo: but is the scoped lifetime also a robust solution for the background worker, where the DbContext object is alive for as long as the application runs? That can be weeks, months long until the next deployment or server restart.

Comment: I didn't know of connection pooling - thanks for this info already! This means creating new DbContexts in the background worker regularly (not super high frequent) wouldn't be that bad after all.

Comment: Your `TimedHostedServices` should create a IOC scope every time they fire, and dispose of it when the task is done.

Comment: @PhilipDaubmeier The scoped lifetime started with receiving a request and stopped with the return of the response. Forget about any BackgroundWorker - the application can stop at any time and restart on the next request.

Comment: I've had similar issues with a HostedService where basically the DbContext lived longer than I wanted (the lifetime of the instance of the HostedService, which can be as long as the app pool is running). In the end I injected a DbContextFactory instead, and just created and disposed contexts as needed. DbContexts are very lightweight and, as others have said, do not incur expensive making of connections, etc. for each instance.

Comment: @ESG: that sounds like the solution I was looking for - stupid question then: how do I tell the IOC container to create a new scope?

Comment: @Sir Rufo: no, the `IHostedService` background worker lives as long as the app pool is running. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: For a long-running tasks you should create your DbContext in a Using block so you don't depend on a single database connection for the lifetime of your appliation.  If your database server restarts, or the connection is broken, you need to be able to simply open a new connection.

Comment: @David Browne: ESGs answer is even more elegant - the timed hosted service spawns a new scope every time I poll from a webservice and write into the db. The DbContext is injected into the worker service which doesnt have to worry about `using` statements and creating DbContexts manually. At the same time the context lives only as long as it is needed (few milliseconds in my case)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should create a scope whenever your `TimedHostedServices` triggers.

Inject the service provider in your constructor:

```
public MyServiceService(IServiceProvider services)
{
    _services = services;
}
```

and then create a scope whenever the task triggers

```
using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
{
    var anotherService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AnotherService>();

    anotherService.Something();
}
```

A more complete example is available [in the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task)

Comment: That was the idea I was looking for. I moved my background work code from the timed hosted service into another class that is created with a new scope everytime the timer triggers (once every 5 mins). No more locking or endlessly living DbContexts, no manual DbContext construction and it works like a charm - thanks a lot!

Comment: this is not really solving the "resource usage overhead and unnecessarily many connection opening/closings" problem, isn't it? As in your scope you have to ask for a DbContext each time.

Comment: For those scenarios, you could configure DbContext pooling, but whether the overhead is an issue in a particular project or not is a different question altogether

Answer (score 8):

Another approach to create own DbContextFactory and instantiate new instance for every query.

```
public class DbContextFactory
{
    public YourDbContext Create()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<YourDbContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(_connectionString)
            .Options;

        return new YourDbContext(options);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
public class Service
{
    private readonly DbContextFactory _dbContextFactory;

    public Service(DbContextFactory dbContextFactory) 
         => _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;

    public void Execute()
    {
        using (var context = _dbContextFactory.Create())
        {
            // use context
        }
    }
}
```

With factory you don't need to worry about scopes anymore, and make your code free of ASP.NET Core dependencies.
You will be able to execute queries asynchronously, which not possible with scoped DbContext without workarounds.
You always be confident about what data saved when calling `.SaveChanges()`, where with scoped DbContext there are possibilities that some entity were changed in other class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm going with ESGs approach, however, as it follows the IoC principle. Also note, that Scopes are not a ASP.NET Core dependency - the native DI with scopes is a first class citizen there but is used in more and more other. NET Core project types, like Azure Functions and even Desktop apps.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension of [ESG's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1251127/esg) answer specifically around hosted services.

```
public class ScopedService<T> : BackgroundService where T : class, IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private T? _instance;
    public ScopedService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _instance?.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            _instance = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();
            await _instance.StartAsync(stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can simply do the following during DI initialization.

```
    services.AddHostedService<ScopedService<Service1>>();
    services.AddHostedService<ScopedService<Service2>>();
```